# Android: Converting a decimal number to time

Tags: android

Android
Im working on and android application that works out the time it takes to reach a destination.
what I am try to figure out is how to set up the result so the answer can be displayed as hours.minutes.seconds or days.hours.minutes.seconds.

1. Would I have to set up an array to get a result like this ?
   or
2. Would the above Q be able to slip up the answer? 
   ie lets say I have an answer of 4.50 (been 4hrs, 30min) would I be able to take the .50 and time it by 0.6 to change the output to 4.30.
   or
3. Can the answer be displayed in a time picker.

ps I have searched this on the forums and google etc. And I have not found and relevent, easy to comprehend answers.
pps Any codes or links would be greatly apprecated thank you.

Comment: You can use the Joda Time library to get such a time format. http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/ But you should convert your elapsed time to millis instead of hours.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use SimpleDateFormat class to do that.

example code:

```
String datastring="15.32.08"
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH.mm.ss");
Date converttoData = sf.parse(datastring);
```

You can easily do that: First to convert a decimal to string(datastring),second,use upper code.

hope the answer can help u.:)